# Rails Radiant CMS tag cloud plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tag-cloud, radiant

I am creating a blog website with Radiant CMS but I need a tag cloud plugin that would work like blogger like visual tag cloud. I found [this](https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/Tags-Extension) but it does not give give the visual tag cloud feature. Is there any known one with the traditional tag cloud visual or must I develop it?

Thanks answerers

Answer (score 0):

If you ran the 'update' rake task, you will find public/stylesheets/tags.css contains some CSS for that. Just make sure to link that css file in your layout (or copy the rules to your own stylesheet), and the tag cloud should look pretty much like you want it to.